# Copy all data in Excel including results removed by filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is it possible to copy all of the data on a sheet including rows that have been removed by an applied filter?

I need to copy the data to another sheet using VBA but it's quite slow to save filter settings, remove the filter, copy data, and then reapply the saved filter settings.

Comment: Duplicate the sheet, then play with the filter in the copied sheet?

Comment: Define data: values, formulas, blanks, formatting? Does the destination contain the filters and do you want them applied? Are you creating a new worksheet, new workbook or copying to an existing worksheet in the same workbook or an existing worksheet in a different workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Drag the tab of the sheet to another positin with mouse, holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (for copying instead of moving it).